# Alter incoming URLs for HTTP/HTTPS to force the “www” subdomain in Tomcat 9

Tags: tomcat, http, subdomain, domain-name

I want every [URL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL) coming into my [Tomcat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Tomcat) web server to carry the `www` subdomain prefix.

How can I have Tomcat alter an incoming URL such as this:

```
http://Example.com/whatever
```

…to include the `www` subdomain prefix:

```
http://www.Example.com/whatever
```

The goal is that my Java Servlets receive URLs that always carry the `www` prefix.

I have been told that [DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System) is not the place to do this. Supposedly, the web server is the proper place to adjust from bare domain to subdomain.

Is [URL redirection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection) what I need? If so, how do I configure Tomcat for that?

Answer (score 0):

If I was doing this I would do it in something like nginx that I would be using to handle redirects like this and probably to force https as well.

The following nginx config should do what you want.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name example.com;

    return 301 http://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
     listen 80;
     listen [::]:80;

     server_name www.example.com;

     location / {
           proxy_pass http://tomcat.server:8080/;
     }
}
```